# Trouble showing showing Posts related to custom post type and taxonomy.

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Having issues showing posts based on  custom post type's custom taxonomy. I can get ALL the posts to show up in the custom post type but not JUST the taxonomy.

here is how I registered Post Types

```
function reg_forms() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Forms', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Form', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Form' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Form' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Form' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Form' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Forms' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Forms' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Forms' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No Forms found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Forms found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Forms'
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Forms for download',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'has_archive'   => true,
  );
  register_post_type( 'forms', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'reg_forms' );

function my_taxonomies_product() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Form Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Form Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Form Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Form Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Form Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Form Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Form Category' ), 
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Form Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Form Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Form Category' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Form Categories' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'form_category', 'forms', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_product', 0 );
```

Here is Query.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query($args = array(
      'post_type' => 'forms',
      'custom_cat' => 'form_category',

      ) );
          // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) 
    {

            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
              $the_query->the_post();
              echo "<div>";
              echo  get_the_title();
              echo "</div>";
              ;?>

              <?php 
            }
          } 

        else {
          wp_reset_postdata();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query($args = array(
      'post_type' => 'forms',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'form_category',
            'field'    => 'slug'
        ),
      ),

    )
);
```

btw - Why do you have a 0 in this add_action?  Remove it or change it to > 0.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_product', 0 );
```

Comment: still nothing shows up. I can get all the forms to show up, just not specific categories.

Comment: is it cause I have hirearchical set to true, and thus it's pulling all categories?

Answer (score 0):

Turns our I needed to use the Tax Query to target the category... ugh.

```
<?php
$myposts = get_posts(array(
    'showposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'forms',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('appeals'))
    ))
);

foreach ($myposts as $mypost) {
      echo $mypost->post_title . '<br/>';

}
?>
```